# class system extension proposal

Tags: haskell

I'm solving some ploblem on generating ancestor instances in Haskell. Recently I found this on Haskell wiki: [Class system extension proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Class_system_extension_proposal). So, I would like to know, are there any solutions for this proposal already?

*Here are the examples from the Proposal:*

> The current class system in Haskell is based on the idea that you can
>   often provide default implementations for class methods at the same
>   time as defining the class, by using other methods of the class or its
>   ancestors. However consider the following hierarchy, adapted from
>   Functor hierarchy proposal and The Other Prelude:
>
> ```
> class Functor m where
>     fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
>
> class Functor m => Applicative m where
>     return :: a -> m a
>
>     apply :: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
>
>     (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
>     ma >> mb = (fmap (const id) ma) `apply` mb
>
> class Applicative m => Monad m where
>     (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
> ```
>
> For all concrete instances of Monad we can define fmap, apply, and
>   (>>)in terms of return and (>>=) as follows:
>
> ```
> fmap f ma = ma >>= (\a -> return (f a))
>
> apply mf ma = mf >>= \f -> ma >>= \a -> return (f a)
>
> ma >> mb = ma >>= \_ -> mb
> ```
>
> In other words, we'd like to be able to write:
>
> ```
> class Applicative m => Monad m where
>     (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>
>     fmap f ma = ma >>= (\a -> return (f a))
>
>     apply mf ma = mf >>= \f -> ma >>= \a -> return (f a)
>
>     ma >> mb = ma >>= \_ -> mb
> ```
>
> and be able to define new instances of Monad just by supplying
>   definitions for return and (>>=) by writing:
>
> ```
> instance Monad T where
>     ma >>= a_mb = ... -- some definition
>
>     return a = ... -- some definition
> ```
>
> Explicit import/export of instances
>
> This is needed so that large programs can be built without fear of
>   colliding instance declarations between different packages. A possible
>   syntax could be:
>
> ```
> module M
>      -- exported instances 
>    ( instance Monad T
>    , instance Functor (F a) hiding (Functor (F Int), Functor (F Char))
>    , F(..)
>    ) where
>
> import Foo (instance Monad a hiding Monad Maybe)
>
> data T a
> data F a b
> ```
>
> where the context is elided because this isn't used in instance
>   selection (at the moment). The import directive tells the compiler to
>   use all Monad instances exported by Foo except for the Monad Maybe
>   instance (it doesn't matter whether or not Foo actually does export a
>   Monad Maybe instance - all that matters here is that we don't want it
>   if there is one).

Comment: You should copy the relevant parts of your link into the question so that the question is robust to linkrot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [`DefaultSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#class-default-signatures) extension allows this. For example, for the `Functor`/`Applicative` example, one could write

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    default fmap :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    fmap = liftA
```

Comment: That is a crappy extension. Better than nothing, yes, but it's extremely limited, it requires superclasses to know about subclasses, and it's really just upside down.